# How to calculate $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}|$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, limsup-and-liminf

I would like to show that the sequence $f_n = \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ is uniformly convergent on the interval $[0,1)$.

I know that the limiting function f of the sequence on this interval is $0$.

I would like to use the fact that $f_n$ is uniformly convergent if $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}  |f_n(x) - f(x)| = 0$.

This leaves me needing to show that:

$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}| = 0$

Intuitively i can see that the limit of the supremum of the sequence tends to $0$ as n tends to infinity. However, I am not sure how to prove this.

Is this the right approach or is there another way to show uniform convergence that is simpler and doesn't involve the limsup.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$,$$\sup_{x\in[0,1)}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}=\frac12,$$since you always have $\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}<\frac12$ and $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}=\frac12$. So,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in[0,1)}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}=\frac12.$$From this, together with the fact that$$\bigl(\forall x\in[0,1)\bigr):\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}=0,$$you can deduce that your sequence dos *not* converge uniformly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, thats very helpful!